# Android Custom View in ListView setSelected(true) Undone

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I have a `ListView` whose items can be in one of three states: selected, multiselected, or none.

When the item is selected it means that the user has just clicked on it (selected it) and the background of the row should change to the selected drawable.

If it is in multiselect, it means that the user long-pressed on an item, and put the list into multiselect mode. That initial item is set to multiselect, and any subsequent item that is clicked will be put into multiselect mode, until multiselect is ended (backspace, unselecting all multiselected items, etc..). The background of an multiselected row should be set to the multiselected drawable.

Otherwise it is in the "none" state and the background is transparent.

The problem I am having is that when an item should be in selected mode, I call `View.setSelected(true)` on the view for the selected position in `getView()`. I have two places in my app where I use this pattern. In one place it works perfectly, but in the other, it appears that something (not me) is calling `View.setSelected(false)` on my selected row after it returns from `getView()`.

Here's how I initialize my ListView (after inflation):

```
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View clickedItem, int position, long id) {
        if(adapter.isMultiSelect()) {
            ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, !adapter.isPositionInMultiSelect(position));
        }
        else {
            adapter.setNewSelectedPosition(position);

            //do something
        }
    }
});
lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MyMultiChoiceModeListener(adapter));
```

`adapter.setNewSelectedPosition()` calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Here's my `getView()`:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {     
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = new MyListRow(context);
    }

    boolean isSelected = isPositionInMultiSelect(position) || position == getSelectedPosition();

    SelectionType selectionType = SelectionType.NONE;
    if(isMultiSelect() && selectedPosition == position) {
        if(isPositionInMultiSelect(position)) {
            selectionType = SelectionType.MULTI_SELECT;
        }
        else {
            selectionType = SelectionType.NONE;
        }
        selectedPosition = NO_SELECTION_POSITION;
    }
    else if(isSelected) {
        if(isMultiSelect()) {
            selectionType = SelectionType.MULTI_SELECT;
        }
        else {
            selectionType = SelectionType.SELECTED_ITEM;
        }
    }

    ((MyListRow) convertView).updateViews(isSelected, selectionType);

    return convertView;
}
```

Here's `MyListRow`:

```
public MyListRow(Context context) {
    super(context);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, this, true);

    setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

    setViewBackground(R.drawable.list_row_selector);

    setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);     
}

public void updateViews(boolean isSelected, SelectionType selectionType) {
    if(isSelected) {
        if(selectionType == SelectionType.MULTI_SELECT) {
            setSelected(false);
        }
        else {
            setSelected(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        setSelected(false);
    }

    //do stuff
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setViewBackground(int res) {
    Drawable d = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(res);
    Rect drawablePadding = new Rect();
    d.getPadding(drawablePadding);
    int top = getPaddingTop() + drawablePadding.top;
    int left = getPaddingLeft() + drawablePadding.left;
    int right = getPaddingRight() + drawablePadding.right;
    int bottom = getPaddingBottom() + drawablePadding.bottom;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
    else {
        setBackground(d);
    }

    setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

Finally, here's `list_row_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed"
    android:state_selected="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_activated"
    android:state_activated="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, `post`ing setSelected(true) makes it work:

```
public void updateViews(boolean isSelected, SelectionType selectionType) {
    if(isSelected) {
        if(selectionType == SelectionType.MULTI_SELECT) {
            setSelected(false);
        }
        else {
            post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setSelected(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        setSelected(false);
    }

    //do stuff
}
```